# Collect JS value and use it in Ruby code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm stuck on a JS & Ruby aspect.

I have got a 4 different inputs on my HTML code and I collect values thanks to JS function.

My JS function looks like :

```
$("input.livraison:checkbox").click(function(){
  var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).prop("name")+"']";
  $(group).prop("checked",false);
  $(this).prop("checked",true);
});
var livraison = $('input[name="livraison"]:checked').val()
```

I would to collect the variable "livraison" to put it into a simple_form for on my Ruby code.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify? You want to use an javascript variable and execute his content into a ruby simple_form declaration?

Comment: Yes exactly. I would like tu use it in a value of this simple_form : <%= simple_form_for [@product], :html=> { id: 'button' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :name, value: "the JS value"%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :price_cents, value: 20000 %>